# Creating complex nested loop in Python with value taken from List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to get this type of output for every grade. The output is only for last grade and number of School working days. First loop is to print number of working days which is an input taken by user. For example 5 so it'll print till friday from monday. Second loop is a nested loop to print stars.
Note - All variables and lists are taken as an input from user.

```
num_of_class=4
num_of_days=5
num_of_lectures=[1,3,3,4] #each element represent num of lectures for each grade upto 4
daylist=["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
lastname=daylist[num_of_days-1]

first=0
for dayrow in daylist[:num_of_days]:
    print(dayrow, end=" ")
print("\r")

for first in range(first, lastelement):
    for second in range(0, num_of_days):
        print ("*", end=" ")
    print("\r")
```

```
output
monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday 
* * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * *
```

```
Expected Output
monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday 
* * * * * 
monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday 
* * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * 
monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday 
* * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * 
monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday 
* * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the purpose:

```
num_of_class=4
num_of_days=5
num_of_lectures=[1,3,3,4] #each element represent num of lectures for each grade upto 4
daylist=["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
lastname=daylist[num_of_days-1]


for i in range(num_of_class):
    print(' '.join(daylist[:num_of_days]))
    for j in range(num_of_lectures[i]):
        print('* ' * num_of_days)
```

Comment: Thank you. It did. Maybe I need to learn and work with functions more often.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following what this is supposed to do but I'll do my best guess at trying to provide a solution here....

Instead of this:

```
for dayrow in daylist[:num_of_days]:
    print(dayrow, end=" ")
print("\r")
```

If your intended output looks like: monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday, an easier solution would be simply to join these list elements together.

```
" ".join(daylist[:num_of_days])
```

As far as the stars go, it looks like what you are trying to do is create a 2D list where the X-axis is number_of_days and the Y-axis is an element from num_of_lectures. However I'm not sure where num_of_class is supposed to be used

```
dayrow = " ".join(daylist[:num_of_days])
for lecture in num_of_lectures:
    print(dayrow)
    row = ("* " * num_of_days).strip()
    for i in range(0, lecture):
        print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, number of element in the lists num_of_lectures is taken based on the value of variable num_of_class.

Comment: Still not quite sure what that means. Can you give me a solid description of what each of these are representing for you?:

num_of_class  # Number Of Grade Levels?

num_of_days  # Number Of Days In Week There Is Class?

num_of_lectures # Number Of Lectures Each Grade Level Takes?

Comment: The representation of all variables you mentioned are correct.